# Envio um POST e como recupero os dados no ANGULAR?

Tags: angular, aplicação-web, http, post

```
onSubmit() {
console.log(this.formulario.value)

this.http.post(this.configUrl, (this.formulario.value)).pipe(
 map(res => res))
.subscribe(dados => console.log(dados))   
}
```

Esse é meu código post, estou enviando uma mensagem para o servidor e ele me retorna um JSON , como eu faria para recuperar isso para pode inserir na minha tela ?

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia Fernando, o método POST do http é para gravar os dados apenas, você apenas recebe o código referente ao status dele (sucesso, erro ou outros). Para recuperar os dados que você gravou e exibir na tela, você precisa realizar outra requisição, mas dessa vez com o método GET.

Ficaria dessa forma:

No seu serviço:

```
recuperaDados() {
  return this.http.get(this.getURL);  
}
```

No seu componente, você pode fazer com o ASYNC PIPE, ou apenas de inscrevendo ao retorno:

```
this.servico.recuperaDados().subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

Dessa forma falta só guardar em uma variável local que possui acesso ao template (HTML).

Espero ter ajudado, tenta dar uma olhada na documentação na parte de Dependency Injection, segue o link https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection